# store lat and lng in arraylist

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting the locations on map and showing the markers just problem is to store all the nearby location lat lang in an array

```
   private void showNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList) {
            int size = nearbyPlaceList.size();
            arrayList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlaceList.get(i);
                String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
                String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                arrayList.add(latLng);
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                Log.d("getnearbyplaces", "marker added");
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
                Log.d("getnearbyplaces", String.valueOf(arrayList));
            }
        }
    }
```

this is exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.waqarraja.googlenearbyplaces, PID: 32030
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.waqarraja.googlenearbyplaces.DataParser.getDuration(DataParser.java:25)
                      at com.example.waqarraja.googlenearbyplaces.DataParser.parseDirection(DataParser.java:120)
                      at com.example.waqarraja.googlenearbyplaces.GetDirectionsData.onPostExecute(GetDirectionsData.java:36)
                      at com.example.waqarraja.googlenearbyplaces.GetDirectionsData.onPostExecute(GetDirectionsData.java:13)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5120)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1814K, 17% free 20722K/24836K, paused 112ms, total 112ms
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
D/DownloadURL: Returning data= {   "destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 39.33.172.119, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
```

Comment: You can save a `ArrayList<LatLng> list`. Whats the issue ?

Comment: sorry it is not working an illegal exception has been accured

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: Add the complete error and code in question .

Comment: this is exception

Comment: the exception is related to api denied in `DataParser`. You should check your google-maps api key

Comment: What API key do you use? Does it have any restriction? Is it the same API key that you use for Android Google Maps?